# Cookies with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, cookies

I am trying to apply cookies in my application, and I did as I read from many tutorials, but I don't get any result and no error is displayed. I want to save authenticated user in cookie and display it in other view! where is the problem please!

**app.js**

```
app.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $location,$state,$http,$window,$rootScope,$cookies){

    $scope.submit = function()
    {
        data = {
            'Email' : $scope.Email,
            'mdp' : $scope.mdp
    };

        $http.post('http://localhost/deb/login.php', data)
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config,result)
        {
            console.log(data);

            if(data.role == 'client'){
                $state.go('view');  
                console.log(data);
                 $scope.myCookie=$cookies.get('cookie');
                $scope.setCookie = function(data){
                  $cookies.put('cookie',data);
                }


             }
```

**view.html**

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="loginCtrl">
{{myCookie}}
```

Comment: Check your cookies by devtools () F12 -> application. If they are marked as HTTPOnly (and mostly auth cookies are ), you can't access them at all

Comment: I checked cookies as you suggest but I didn't get your idea! can you explain please!

Comment: 1. Check if your cookies existed. If no, then add them.
2. If they existed you added them - check if they are marked HttpOnly flag. If yes - you can't access them at all. They are secured from js. 

Chrome -> F12-> Application-> Cookies -> Table on the right side

Comment: why do you try to get the cookie before you declare it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try **ngCookies
install it first**

```
npm install --save angular-cookies
```

add its **path** in index.html

```
<script src="path/to/angular-cookies.js"></script>
```

Finally, load the module in your application by adding it as a dependent module:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngCookies']);
```

then edit your controller as follow

```
app.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $location,$state,$http,$window,$rootScope,$cookieStore){

$scope.submit = function()
{
    data = {
        'Email' : $scope.Email,
        'mdp' : $scope.mdp
};

    $http.post('http://localhost/deb/login.php', data)
    .then(function(res)
    {


        console.log(res.data);

        if(res.data.role == 'client'){
            $state.go('view');  
            $cookieStore.put('email',res.data.email);
            $cookieStore.put('token',res.data.token);
         }
```

and when you want to access cookie

```
$cookieStore.get('cookieName');
```

for more check the [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies)

**Edit**

now Show everything differently as

```
$scope.name=$cookieStore.get('email');
```

Comment: just as you did it befor $scope.myCookie = $cookieStore.get('cookieName');

Comment: and in html view.html

<div class="container" ng-controller="loginCtrl">
{{myCookie}}

Comment: That's what I did, but I don't know why it doesn't work

Comment: try console.log($cookieStore.get('cookieName'));

Comment: and see if it display something in browser console

Comment: in console I get Email and password!

Comment: thats it cookies are set

Comment: Yeas thank you , I can see data in console, now I just can't display it in html file

Comment: try if its nested {{myCookie.email}}

Comment: still have no resulat

Comment: check i have edited if condition and added multiple cookies and try to display

Comment: Now I can see that two cookies are set, but nothing is displayed in html file